# How to use @Configuration to define configurations runtime?

Tags: java, spring

I am pretty new to spring so please bear with me and feel free to suggest more reading with right links if you see necessary.I am using a class to define a connection settings for different Rest endpoints I will be calling out to (username port etc.). So I am thinking of storing them to application.properties as follows:

```
twitter.username="a"
twitter.password="b"
twitter.host="www.twitter.com"
facebook.username="c"
facebok.password="d"
facebook.host="www.facebook.com"
```

Now I want to define a class that will take all the prefix (such as "twitter" or "facebook") and return me the configuration class based off of the corresponding properties in applicaton.properties.

I was thinking of doing something similar to following:

```
@Configuration    
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RESTConfiguration
{

    class RESTServer{
        public String username;
        public String password;
        public String host;
        private RESTServer(String username, String password, String host)
        {
             this.username = username;
             this.password = password;
             this.host = host;
        }

    }
    @Autowied
    private String ednpointName;

    @Bean
    public RESTServer restServer(Environment env)
    {
        return new RESTServer(env.getProperty(ednpointName + ".user"),
                env.getProperty(ednpointName + ".password"),
                env.getProperty(ednpointName+".host"));
    }
}
```

But it clearly won't work since there will be only one Bean and I won't have a way to pass multiple endpointName. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to use a factory design pattern. Something along the lines of:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RESTConfiguration
{
        @Bean
        public RESTServerFactory restServer()
        {
            return new RESTServerFactory()
        }
}

public class RESTServer {
        public String username;
        public String password;
        public String host;
        private RESTServer(String username, String password, String host)
        {
             this.username = username;
             this.password = password;
             this.host = host;
        }
}

public class RESTServerFactory {
        @Autowired Environment env;

        public RESTServer getRESTServer(String endpointName)
        {
            return new RESTServer(env.getProperty(ednpointName + ".username"),
                env.getProperty(ednpointName + ".password"),
                env.getProperty(ednpointName+".host"));
        }
}
```

An example of using this factory:

```
@Autowired RESTServerFactory factory;

public RESTServer createServer(String endpoint) {
    return factory.getRESTServer(endpoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do:

1. Move `RestServer` outside to its own class, it should not be an inner class of `RestConfiguration`.
2. Use `scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE` in order to allow creation of several instances of `RestServer`, one per injection point:

   ```
     @Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE)
     public RESTServer restServer(Environment env) { ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Luiggi Mendoza. How do I create multiple injection points?

Comment: @brotherofmysister every time you use `@Autowired RESTServer restServer` as field in other class.

Comment: I see. But then how do I create different instances based on the endpointName? I want one bean created for endpointName="twitter" and one for endpointName="facebook".

Comment: Well, your current design won't support that since `ednpointName` field cannot change it's value. I would recommend, instead, having two methods, one per configuration.

Comment: Well my problem is I do not know how many beans I will need i.e. how many endpoints will I need to connect to yet. What you are suggesting it seems like I will need to add  a method every time  I create a new endpoint. Maybe I need a way of creating beans dynamically based on passing an endpoint name? Any ideas on that?